# Combining LINQ queries to get unique records

Tags: linq

I'm trying to figure out a way of combining these 2 LINQ queries. The first one creates a list of holiday customers and the second one de-dupes the list based on the email address.

Whats the most succinct way of combining them?

```
        var allNonBuyers = (from a in allCustomers
                            where !(from q in db.Quotes
                                    where q.CreationDate > DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(duration)
                                    join p in db.Passengers on q.QuoteGUID equals p.QuoteGUID
                                    where q.PolicyNumber != null
                                    select p.EmailAddress).Contains(a.EmailAddress)
                            select new { a.QuoteGUID, a.Title, a.FirstName, a.LastName, a.EmailAddress, a.Telephone });

        var distinctNonBuyers = from buyer in allNonBuyers
                                group buyer by buyer.EmailAddress
                                    into gbuyer
                                    select gbuyer.First();
```

Answer (score 1):

You normally don't need to - because LINQ has delayed execution, when you ask for the result it will all be combined.  If this is Linq-To-Sql then it will be executed as one statement (if possible) against the database.

Comment: So really, to keep things fairly simple and readable its best to go with multiple queries?

Comment: @FloatLeft yep, but I always test my queries in Linq pad first, sometimes Linq2SQL generates a lot of sql statements when you don't except it.

Comment: Linq has deferred and nondeferred operators.  As long as you're not using a nondeferred operator the query won't be executed until enumeration.  .First() is a nondeferred operator so it will execute at that point.

Comment: Can the 2 queries be rewitten as one query by using the "into" keywork instead of using 2 vars

Comment: If you want it as one query just replace the allNonBuyers variable with the actual query